# How to check with the help of filters if client send a valid JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following request:

[image]

As you can see it's not a valid JSON. Even it's not a JSON. IT's just a random set of letters. I would like to check that client can't pass body like on the screen before on my Web API. If it happens I would like to send something like:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "description": "Invalid JSON"
}
```

So, I have the following filter:

```
public class MyValidateJson : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            // check if json is valid
            using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
            var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            try
            {
                JToken.Parse(body);
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException ex)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new
                {
                    status = "error",
                    description = "Invalid JSON input"
                });

                base.OnActionExecuting(context);
            }
```

But I can't read body. I always have empty string. And as the result I always have invalid JSON. How can I improve my filter?

### Update

Maybe my explanation of the problem is not clear, I'll try to fix it. So, I would like to avoid this situation:

[image]

As you can see `{"":["Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 1, position 1."]}` - is ... what is this for my client? For the client it has to be something like:

```
{
   "status": "error",
   "description": "Your JSON is invalid, we are sorry ((("
}
```

but not `{"":["Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 1, position 1."]}`

I have the following controller:

```
   [Route("/api/v1.0/startup")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] CustomerChangeViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
    ...
```

And view model too:

```
 public class CustomerChangeViewModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("idfa")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required idfa")]
        public string Idfa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("idfv")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required idfv")]
        public string Idfv { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_build_number")]
        [JsonProperty("app_build_number")]
        public string AppBuildNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("app_version")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_version")]
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }
    ...
```

How I can get this behavior? I mean with nice answer (not exception text).

Comment: You should use DTO class which You want to receive as parameter in Your controller's endpoint. You can validate every single property automatically using DataAnnotations Attributes and automatically return proper informations. If no one will answer, I'll post my answer in some minutes.

Comment: Yes I can, But... But it works only when I pass valid JSON object. If I pass invalid JSON (just random string for example) I have as the answer exception text instead of understandable information about invalid JSON.

Comment: @Genotypek I don't need to check is fields valid or not in the filter. I just want to check if JSON valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DTO` (Data Transfer Object) class to receive and validate Your desired JSON with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.
In my case it's for account register:

```
    public class AccountRegisterDTO
    {
        [Required] // This property is obligatory, it MUST exist in JSON
        [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Username must be at least 6 characters long")] // Must be minimum 6 characters long
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*$", ErrorMessage = "Username can contain only letters and numbers")] // Must Match the RegEx
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 8 characters long")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\d])((?=.*[^\w\s])|(?=.*[ ])).*$", ErrorMessage = "Password don't meet passwords policy")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email address is not valid")] // Automatically validate if e-mail address is correct
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

Usage is very simple, it looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost("Register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] AccountRegisterDTO registerAccount)
        {
            // Code will not even reach this point if JSON is not valid according to DataAnnotations Attributes
        }
```

For passed arguments:

[image]

Returned errors looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes. Looking on Your update, I'm not able to provide correct answer then, sorry.

Comment: It's ok) I thought too, that DTO (view model) and default validation will protect me for cases like that) But it does not work.

Comment: I think, filter is good idea. Am I right? Or there are any ways?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't get the request body in Action Filter , so that in filter it doesn't correctly check the Json parse and return custom error . You can try below codes to get the request body in `OnActionExecuting`:

```
var bodyStr = "";
var req = context.HttpContext.Request;           
req.EnableRewind();
req.Body.Position = 0;
using (var stream = new StreamReader(req.Body))
{
   bodyStr = stream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But your solution leads me to the following exception `System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper' `. I have tried `req.EnableBuffering();` instead `EnableRewind` but it gives me empty body again(

Comment: What is your .net core version ?  // For ASP.NET 2.1
         use context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
        // For ASP.NET 3.1
        use context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();

Comment: @NanYu By luck I found your post and it answers my question I had last week. Thanks! =) If you wish please post your solution for  ASp.NET Core 3.1 in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861461/get-rawbody-from-httpcontext-of-actionexecutioncontext-in-asp-net-core and I can accept your answer there as well

Comment: @NanYu I just noticed that you don't need `.EnableRewind()` or `.EnableBuffering()` at all. It's possible to omit that line

Comment: @citronas , Ok  . And i guess you add the extension method in startup.cs